# Entity Framework: where field starts with number

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using MVC3 with Entity Framework 4.1 and I've got a grid that is paged by the first character of the company name. I have it working great but some companies start with a number. I'm using the following LINQ query to get the companies starting with the selected number, but how can I select those starting with a number?

```
    var b = (from c in dbContext.Companies
             where c.CompanyName.StartsWith(selectedCharacter)
             select c)
```

I've tried:

```
 where char.IsNumber(l.CompanyName[0])
```

But,  I get an error because it doesn't know how to convert it to SQL.

Edit: I know I could just do .CompanyName.StartsWith("1") || .CompanyName.StartsWith("2"), etc.. Is there a better way?
.
Any Ideas?

Comment: And what is a problem with c.CompanyName.StartsWith(selectedCharacter) as selectedCharacter still can be '1', '2' ....

Comment: Since I posted the question I tested it using  .CompanyName.StartsWith("1") || .CompanyName.StartsWith("2") and it's probably the best way but it just seemed repetitive.  The SQL is what you'd expect:
WHERE ([Extent1].[CompanyName] LIKE '1%') OR ([Extent1].[CompanyName] LIKE '2%') OR ([Extent1].[CompanyName] LIKE '3%').. etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
var numbers = new string[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"};
var b = (from c in dbContext.Companies
         where numbers.Contains(c.CompanyName.Substring(0,1))
         select c).ToList();
```

You could run into an issue though if your company is Empty.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I get the following exception:    
Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: You can just change the new char to string. Will update my answer now.

Comment: I tried that earlier, but it gives the following exception: 
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Jamiegs, does SubString(0,1) work? It Works! :) check my updated answer.